# For Dummies: Parsing XMLs which don't include "=" with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I only ever find questions on stackoverflow in the vein of `<AB> CD = EF </AB>`, but hardly without. How would I parse this file in C# with LINQ?:

```
<root>
    <aa ID=1000>
        <bb>*Value1*</bb>
        <cc>*Value2*</cc>
        <dd>*Value3*</dd>
        <ee>*Value4*</ee>
    </aa>
    <zz ID=2000>
        <bb>*Value5*</bb>
        <cc>*Value6*</cc>
        <dd>*Value7*</dd>
        <ee>*Value8*</ee>
    </zz>
    <aa ID=3000>
        <bb>*Value9*</bb>
        <cc>*Value10*</cc>
        <dd>*Value11*</dd>
        <ee>*Value12*</ee>
    </aa>
    <bb>*Value13*</bb>
    <cc>*Value14*</cc>
    <dd>*Value15*</dd>
    <ee>*Value16*</ee>
</root>
```

I only want to read **bb**'s and **dd**'s, *if* the are within a **aa**. So my result (preferably but not necessarily a List) would be:

```
*Value1*
*Value3*
*Value9*
*Value11*
```

Edit: Added root-level. To the comments: The zz-Tag is purposefully placed, as are the bb-Tags (etc.) on the same level.

Comment: That's not valid XML, attributes must be quoted & there is no root element, is that the real data?

Comment: Double check and make sure your posted xml is correct.  You have both "aa" tags and "zz" tags.  Also you xml is not well formed and have any array at the root level.  Well formed xml only has one tag at root level.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that that is not valid XML it would be something in the line of (pseudocode)

```
XDocument.Parse(yourxml).GetChildren().Where(child => child.Name == "aa").GetChildren().Where(child2 => child2.Name == "bb" || child2.Name == "dd").Select(x => x.Value)
```

This should do the work. It's pseudocode but I don't remember exactly the XDocument method names